# CSS Cleanup--is body h2 redundant?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm cleaning up CSS from a previous designer. The file is messy. One example I'm pretty sure is redundant, I'd just like a confirmation to ease my conscience.

```
body h2{...}
```

Declaring just h2 would be sufficient here, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use `body h2{...}` only if you wanted to override an existing `h2 {...}` declaration. Declaring `h2` on its own is perfectly acceptable otherwise.

Comment: But shouldn't all h2's reside in the body, and therefore make it redundant?

Comment: In the HTML, YES, h2 does reside in the body, but you don't have to declare it in the CSS.  A good read: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: It's not really redundant, it's more "specific", but yes, is it not required unless you want to override.

Comment: This, I didn't know!: "If two selectors apply to the same element, the one with higher specificity wins."

Comment: Jeff: it's good to know, especially when you want to avoid traps like "!important"

Comment: Yeah, the CSS file I'm cleaning up also has 348 !important declarations. Maybe a few less, I've removed some already.

Answer (score 0):

To auto detect redundant and unused CSS classes, try using this library: [css-checker](https://github.com/ruilisi/css-checker).

It helps to scan your codebase automatically by one command: 'css-checker'. I think it's always better to rely on automatic code checking tools than read all codes manually to find improvements.

The `css-check` can scan your CSS code along with your js/jsx/html/ts/tsx code to find unused CSS code (optional).

##### Install

- You can access to the package via `go install`:

```
go install github.com/ruilisi/css-checker@latest
```

(With go version before 1.17, use go get github.com/ruilisi/css-checker). Or download from releases

- Or from npm:

```
npm install -g css-checker-kit
```

##### Start Checking

`cd` to your `Project Path`. Then just run:

```
css-checker
```

It can scan your code and give you feedback like this image: [demo result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTXIJ.png)

You can also add ignore paths like this: `css-checker -ignores=node_modules,packages,*.spec.ts`.

To check unused CSS classes (beta), use: `css-checker -unused`

But anyway, the `css-checker` helps in checking my projects in seconds, and provides hundreds of similar and redundant classes for me to improve. You can check out the package from the Github link:  [css-checker](https://github.com/ruilisi/css-checker)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).